# Error with re-open votes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

In the review tab, yesterday when I logged in there was nine questions pending in re-open votes. Most of these were older and the context was that they had been edited, but there were just so many -- normally there's some luck involved if a person happens to find three or four items requiring review, let along in the same category. Most of the time that includes something tagged as both a first post and late answer simultaneously.

Today when I logged in, there were **forty-one items requiring review in the re-open category. Several of them things I had already addressed yesterday. Also, when I went through a few, the numbers were way off. I got through three and the system logged that ten, fifteen and more had been addressed.** What's up with that? Does that mean other people are getting the funky numbers on reviews pending for closed questions and not just me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Automatic re-open procedures just got changed.

> Currently, this means that a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to delete it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still tweaking the exact thresholds for these, but right now they're fairly generous - however, the most popular closed questions are being added to the queue *first*.

See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078) for details.

Comment: Lame, sigh. I know we're not getting that many closed-edits so the popularity must be tagging them. We've been somewhat lax about deleting bad closed questions but I guess we should...

Comment: Ha, searching for "closed:1" there's 300 or so.  Start flagging stuff we don't want coming back for deletion, folks!